# Fluid Email - required privilege is not held by the client

Tags: c#, liquid, fluent, mailkit

I am working on a mail service and trying to use Fluid Email with mail kit.

When the line `await email.SendAsync()` is executed, it throws **"required privilege is not held by the client "**

I trying to resolve with multiple changes in the file systems, but it doesn't help!

Comment: Randomly changing file system permissions is not likely to work unless you know *exactly* what file permissions need to change (or if the issue is related to file permissions *at all*). In nearly every exception case, the "where was the exception thrown?" is just as if not more important than the message itself. Was the exception thrown when trying to access a file on the file system or was it thrown when creating a socket?